# Configure JsNLog with NLog for RequestId logging under Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog, jsnlog

After consulting the [JsNLog docs](http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/HowTo/RequestIds) and the 2 posts I found on SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485108/getting-jsnlog-to-log-with-nlog) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249438/nlog-how-to-access-requestid)) there were still question marks about the best solution for logging the RequestId coming from JsNLog for Javascript log entries. So far I came up with this:

**(1)** In **_Layout.cshtml** use the JsNLog taghelper, but place the HttpContext.TraceIdentifier there directly, instead of using JSNLog.JavascriptLogging.RequestId(ViewContext.HttpContext) which does the same under under the hood:

```
<jl-javascript-logger-definitions request-id="@ViewContext.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier" />
```

**(2)** Configure NLog to used the *WhenEmpty Layout Renderer*. It will log the HttpContext.TraceIdentifier for all events where the header "JSNLog-RequestId" (submitted by JsNLog javascript) is not set:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="log-all-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${aspnet-request:header=JSNLog-RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}} ${longdate}| ... other entries ... />
```

Make sure the the NLog.config contains

```
<extensions>
  <!-- Make these renderers available: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore -->
  <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

This way we find the same RequestId (aka TraceIdentifier) for server side and client side log entries which belong together.

This solution works, and feels quite okay (after @Rolf Kristensen's comments were implemented).
Does anyone have a better one?

Comment: Have no advice about integration of JsNLog, but consider changing the NLog coalesce into this: `"${mdc:item=JsNLogTraceIdentifier:whenEmpty:${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}} .."` (Much cleaner and much faster)

Comment: Maybe you can skip the hook into OnLogging with this: `"${aspnet-request:header=JSNLog-RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}} .. "`

Comment: More advanced version, that also checks AspNetCore-Header: `"${aspnet-request:header=JSNLog-RequestId:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}} ..."`

Comment: @Rolf Kristensen: With your first two modifications I think it's a lot better, especially because the OnLogging hook went away. I updated the solution accordingly. Tnx